# allowBackup="true" not saving data after uninstalling

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

The [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#Files) say:

> By default, Auto Backup includes files in most of the directories that
>   are assigned to your app by the system

- Shared preferences files
- Files saved to your app's internal storage

etc

However, my app currently stores a SharedPreference item that isn't being saved after uninstalling.

Before I uninstall my app, my shared preference `sharedPref.getInt("locationCount", 0)` is `2`. But when I uninstall and reinstall, it's reset back to it's original value of `0`.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".CustomApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Any idea why it isn't saving?

Answer (score 0):

Backups occur automatically when all of the following conditions are met:

The user has enabled backup on the device. In Android 9, this setting is in Settings > System > Backup.

At least 24 hours have elapsed since the last backup.

The device is idle.

The device is connected to a Wi-Fi network (if the device user hasn't opted in to mobile-data backups).